# output filename, not string with select-string

Tags: powershell, grep

I'm using powershell to "grep" my source code for a particular string.  If the string is in the file, I would like the name of the file, not the line of code that contains the string.

I would also like the name of the file, just once, not listed for as many times as the file exists.

I'm currently using:

```
gci . -include "*.sql" -recurse | select-string -pattern 'someInterestingString'
```

Now I understand that the output of select-string is some sort of ojbect, and what I'm seeing in the console is, i'm guessing, the `ToString()` of that object.  I assume that I could use `format-table` to control the output of the select-string, and I suppose `sort` to get distinct values only.

but that's a lot of guessing.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I don't think I completely understand what you're trying to do. If you want the output grouped by file, you can pipe into `Format-Table` with the `-GroupBy` parameter:

```
gci . -include "*.sql" -recurse `
    | select-string -pattern 'someInterestingString' `
    | Format-Table -GroupBy Path
```

If you want to get only the names of the files that match without any other info, you can use `Select-Object` with the `-Unique` parameter:

```
gci . -include "*.sql" -recurse `
    | select-string -pattern 'someInterestingString' `
    | Select-Object -Unique Path
```

If you're interested in only the file name, regardless whether the name itself appears multiple times in your hierarchy, then you can select the `Filename` property instead.

---

Note: The `Get-Member` cmdlet is a great help in figuring out what properties exist on an object:

```
gci . -include "*.sql" -recurse `
    | select-string -pattern 'someInterestingString' `
    | Get-Member
```

You can also use its alias `gm` instead.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of detailed answer that I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: In order for `Select-Object` to return a string instead of an object with a single `Path` property, use `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path -Unique`

Comment: `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Filename -Unique` will give the filename as output

Answer (score 17):

When I'm doing this I just use the -List parameter - yes it does display the line of code but you only get one line per file (no matter how many matches there are):

```
PS> Get-ChildItem . -r *.cs | Select-String XmlNode -list

Commands\SnapinHelp\CmdletInfo.cs:27:        public List<XmlNode> InputTypes;
Commands\SnapinHelp\GetSnapinHelpCommand.cs:124:            WriteXmlNodeList(c...
Commands\SnapinHelp\ParameterInfo.cs:73:        XmlNode FindNode(XmlDocument doc)
Commands\Xml\XmlCommandBase.cs:65:            RegisterInputType<XmlNode>(Proce...
```

If you want the path:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem . -r *.cs | Select-String XmlNode -list | 
    Format-Table Path

Path
--------
C:\Users\Keith\Pscx\Src\PscxSnapin\Commands\SnapinHelp\CmdletInfo.cs
C:\Users\Keith\Pscx\Src\PscxSnapin\Commands\SnapinHelp\GetSnapinHelpCommand.cs
C:\Users\Keith\Pscx\Src\PscxSnapin\Commands\SnapinHelp\ParameterInfo.cs
C:\Users\Keith\Pscx\Src\PscxSnapin\Commands\Xml\XmlCommandBase.cs
```

Or if you really only want the filename:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem . -r *.cs | Select-String XmlNode -list | 
    Format-Table Filename

Filename
--------
CmdletInfo.cs
GetSnapinHelpCommand.cs
ParameterInfo.cs
XmlCommandBase.cs
```

Comment: Much simpler than the (more generic) solution above... +1.

Comment: Only down side to this approach is that if binary files are in the search path the first line maybe the whole file.

Comment: @Tolga To remove binaries, just use `-exclude *.dll, *.pdb,  *.cache, *.exe` in **get-childitem**, or any other binary extensions that appear.

Answer (score 4):

I found it easier to do

```
(...|select-string "search").Path
```

Comment: This works, but it will return the file's path each time the searched for string is found in the file.

Comment: Despite the above observation, this simple, short, and elegant.   Try i!