# Powershell select-string: get search success boolean and file paths

Tags: powershell

Following on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499575/output-filename-not-string-with-select-string) on Powershell's `select-string`, I'm wondering how in the following pipeline, you can extract multiple return values from various parts of the pipeline.

```
Get-ChildItem "*.*" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'someMatchingCriteria.*'} | select-string -pattern 'someInterestingString' | Select-Object -Unique Path
```

Specifically, I'd like to know how to get a boolean from the `select-string` telling whether anything was actually found or not, as well as any files paths that were found to contain the search string so that I can then do an if statement to either stop and announce which files were found to contain the string, or continue without printing anything.

If I just put a `$test=` out front of that line, it returns the path inside inside a `@{ }`, but I think the select-string by itself will generate a boolean if you use `-quiet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have it, you just have to test for it & output the results.

```
$searchresults = Get-ChildItem "*.*" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'someMatchingCriteria.*'} | select-string -pattern 'someInterestingString' | Select-Object -Unique Path


if ($searchresults -eq $null) {
    "No matches found"
} else {
    "Matches found in the following files"
    $searchresults  | foreach {$_.Path}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something like this myself just now. Does it make sense to replace `$searchresults -eq $null` with `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($searchresults)`?

Comment: `$searchresults` isn't a string if you get results - it's a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` as @KeithHill points out above, so you'll get an invalid result (in a test I just ran, you'll get True even when results are returned) because your types don't match and there's no coercion/casting that can be done properly.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use the `-List` parameter on `Select-String`.  It will stop after the first successful match e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'someMatchingCriteria.*'} | 
    Select-String -pattern 'someInterestingString' -List | 
    Foreach {$_.Path}
```

Select-String always returns a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` object so if you only want the path, just select that one property - `Path`.